# error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.XR.XRNode' to 'string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public float[,,,] HmdPosition = new float [1,1,6,1];
public Vector3 HmdRotation;
....
....
HmdPosition[0, 0, i,0] = UnityEngine.XR.InputTracking.GetLocalPosition(node);
HmdRotation = GameObject.Find(node).transform.rotation;
```

I am using this code to save the parameters(transform) of HMD and controller both rotation and position in an array but I got these two errors :

first : "error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' to 'float' "
second: "error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.XR.XRNode' to 'string'"
Does anyone have any idea?

(I guess I have to change the definition of my array but how? and sorry that I'm not master in unity and c# both) btw is it possible to save the local position and orientation the HMD and controllers with this method?

Comment: Can you change `Steve` to a number? No, right? Because that would make no sense unless there is some special way. Well that's what the error is telling you that it cannot convert `XRNode` to a `string`. If there is a special way of converting it, you need to explicitly write code and tell the runtime how to convert from one to the other.

Comment: Second part: Quaternion to Vector3 conversion is usally done using euler angles
`HmdRotation = GameObject.Find(node).transform.rotation.eulerAngles;`
(see documentation [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html))

And yes, you can store your local position and orientation, but for more detailed help more information is necessary.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for your explanation. I actually need to save the HMD and controllers position and rotation to feed them to my CNN TensorFlow model in unity and estimate the position and rotation of the elbow and shoulder based on that.

Answer (score 0):

1. [`XRNode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.XRNode.html) is an `enum` .. you are using it like a string in

   ```
    Find(node)
   ```

   rather use

   ```
    Find(node.ToString())
   ```
2. You are assigning a `Quaternion` to a `Vector3` variable in

   ```
    HmdRotation = GameObject.Find(node.ToString()).transform.rotation;
   ```

   rather use e.g.

   ```
    HmdRotation = GameObject.Find(node.ToString()).transform.eulerAngles;
   ```
3. You are assigning a `Vector3` to a `float` in

   ```
    HmdPosition[0, 0, i, 0] = UnityEngine.XR.InputTracking.GetLocalPosition(node);
   ```

   You either can only store one of the components `x`, `y` or `z` or should change your data structure. A `Vector3` as the name says is made of three `float` components not one.

---

In general: What is a 4-dimensional array good for if 3 of your dimensions anyway only allow one single layer..??

It is difficult to give further advice without seeing the rest of your code and knowing your actual intentions but

> is it possible to save the local position and orientation the HMD and controllers with this method?

Well currently you get a bunch of exceptions .. so no!

What you describe would need to store one `Vector3` position + one `Quaternion` or `Vector3` rotation. And this whole thing three times for the HMD + two controllers.

So if you really want to serialize this into a `float` array in total this would require at least 18 values.